# How to find the probability of the event that exactly two of the three events occur?

Tags: probability

My professor posted some practice problems with answers (without explanation) for our midterm and this was one of them:

Three independent events have respective probabilities, $\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{4}$

a.) Find the probability of the event that exactly two of the three events occur

b.) Find the probability of the even that at least two of the three events occur.

Answer:

a.)  $\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{5}\frac{3}{4} +  \frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{4}+  \frac{2}{3}\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{4}$

b.) $1 -(\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{4} +  \frac{2}{3}\frac{2}{5}\frac{3}{4}+  \frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{4}+  \frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{4})$

Could someone please explain how he derived the answer (referencing any laws, theorems, properties, formulas, etc)

Comment: Ahh sorry, that was a typo. Thanks for noticing. Edited

Comment: ${3}\choose{2}$ so there are 3 ways to choose two of the probabilities. AB(Not C) BC(Not A) AC(Not B). Calculate for each one (multiply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a) he's simply adding up the probabilities.  The first term is the probability that the first two events happen and the third one does not, for instance.

In b) he's getting the complement of the event that no more than one event occurs.  The first three terms are the probabilities that exactly one event occurs (similar to a) and the last term is the probability that none of the events occurs.

As far as justification goes, the multiplications are okay because the events are independent.  (Recall that if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $A$ and $B^c$ are also independent.)  The additions are justified because all the events are mutually exclusive.  These are two extremely important facts.  Make sure you understand them.

Comment: A little confusing, instead of saying "adding" the probabilities say "adding the product of them". Good job anyway :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot!

Comment: @saulspatz I guess the part I was confused about (and still am) is how he made his choices for changing the numerators before the addition of the fractions.

Comment: @Forextrader If the probability of an event is $p$, the probability that it does not occur is $1-p$.  Is that what you are asking?  If not, please give a very specific point that you don't understand.  Something like, "How did he get $ \frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{4}$ in part a?"

Comment: @saulspatz Yes sorry, should have been more explicit. How did he get the $\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{5}\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{4}$ from part a

Comment: @Forextrader  In the first of those, $\frac13$ and $\frac14$ are the probabilities that the first and third events occur, respectively, and $\frac35$ is the probability that the second event does not occur.  In each term, we have the probability that exactly one of the events does not occur.  Since the events are all independent, we get the probability that all conditions are satisfied by multiplying the probabilities of the individual conditions.  Does this clear it up?

Comment: Ah Ah ah!!!! I see now. Ok makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz I guess im wondering how you would know to apply what my professor applied.

Comment: I would do it exactly the same way as he did.  I don't know what else to say.